# Classes: Instantiating Object Confusion

Tags: c++, class, instantiation

Below is code for a simple book list with a class to store book names and isbn numbers into an overloaded function using a vector. This program runs fine and I can test it by returning a specific name (or isbn) using an accessor function from my class.

*Question:* I tried calling (instantiating?) a constructor with parameters from my class but it would not work, so I commented it out. Yet I was still able to run the program without error. From my main below - **//BookData bkDataObj(bookName, isbn);**

From watching tutorials, I thought I always had to make an object for a specific constructor from a class that I needed to call? My program definitely still uses my overloaded constructor and function declaration **BookData(string, int);** without making an object for it in main first.
Thanks for any help or input on this matter.

**Main**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "BookData.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string bookName[] = { "Neuromancer", "The Expanse", "Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?", "DUNE" };
    int isbn[] = { 345404475, 441569595, 316129089, 441172717 };

    //BookData bkDataObj(bookName, isbn);     //how did program run without instantiating object for class?

    vector <BookData> bookDataArr;

    int arrayLength = sizeof(bookName) / sizeof(string);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        bookDataArr.push_back(BookData(bookName[i], isbn[i]));
    }
    cout << "Book 4 is: " << bookDataArr[3].getBookNameCl();      //test if works

    return 0;
}
```

**BookData.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class BookData
{
public:
    BookData();
    BookData(string, int);       //wasn't I supposed to make an object for this constructor in my main?

    string getBookNameCl();
    int getIsbnCl();

private:
    string bookNameCl;
    int isbnCl;
};
```

**BookData.cpp**

```
#include "BookData.h"

BookData::BookData() {
    bookNameCl = " ";
    isbnCl = 0;
}

BookData::BookData(string bookNameOL, int isbnOL) {      //how did I use this function 
    bookNameCl = bookNameOL;                             //definition without an object in main?
    isbnCl = isbnOL;
}

string BookData::getBookNameCl() {                 //can still return a book name
    return bookNameCl;
}

int BookData::getIsbnCl() {
    return isbnCl;
}
```

Comment: You didn't use `bkDataObj` anywhere, so there's no reason for a compilation error if you don't create it at all. The reason why that line didn't work is that your constructor expects a single string and an int, not arrays.

Comment: That makes sense on not getting any errors, and good to know that I can't use an array there... but I guess where I am confused now is: How was I able to actually use my class definitions in main if I didn't actually make the object, bkDataObj for them? i.e. getBookNameCl

Comment: You're creating a temporary unnamed `BookData` object right here: `BookData(bookName[i], isbn[i])` and this temporary object is moved to the backing storage of `bookDataArr` using the move constructor the compiler automatically generates for a class with the "special member functions" your class defines. You may want to use `bookDataArr.emplace_back(bookName[i], isbn[i]);` though to avoid the move operation required for `push_back`...

Comment: @ps2088 Constructors are special types of functions. They are not called on an existing instance, you actually cannot call them directly at all yourself. They are a piece of code that runs when a new instance is being created. `this` in that context is the object that is being initialized.

Comment: the constructor is what you call to create an instance. You do not need to create an instance before you can call the constructor

Comment: are you confused because there is no `Book book("foo",42);` in your code? Not every object created has to have a name

Comment: Thank you all for your great input - My question has been cleared up. I was unaware that you could create an object that way without actually naming it, thus my confusion. This makes everything much more straightforward for me now.